# Without List permission Azure Key Vault 'Forbidden' error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

**TL;DR:** Without List permission Asp.Net Core 2.2 Web App deployed in Azure fails with Error - `Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'` at startup when using `AzureServiceTokenProvider`

I am working on Asp.Net Core 2.2 Web App and I am aware how Azure Key Vault works and how Web App deployed in Azure can access Keys, Secrets and Certificates from key valut.

Below is my current configuration:

I have created an Azure Key Vault to store subscription information of all my clients:

[image: Azure Key Vault with multiple secrets]

Then I created Azure Web App and created Identity for it:

[image: Web app with Identity created]

Later in Azure Key Vault Access Policies I granted this App Get and List secret permission.

[image: Azure Secret Access Policy]

I didn't want to hard code any secrets in my code thus I used `AzureServiceTokenProvider` to connect and get the secrets, below is my Program.cs file code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog.Common;
using NLog.Web;

namespace AzureSecretsTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
            try
            {
                InternalLogger.LogFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "logs", "nlog-internals.txt");
                var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
                host.Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
                NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
            }
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) =>
                {
                    //https://anthonychu.ca/post/secrets-aspnet-core-key-vault-msi/
                    var keyVaultEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEYVAULT_ENDPOINT");
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
                    {
                        var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                        var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                        builder.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
                    }
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

And below is my simple Startup.cs file with code to access the Secrets from Azure Key Vault:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace AzureSecretsTest
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                string configValue = configuration["OneOfTheSecretKey"];
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                var children = configuration.GetChildren();
                sb.AppendLine($"Is null or whitespace: {string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(configValue)}, Value: '{configValue}'");
                foreach (IConfigurationSection item in children)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine($"Key: {item.Key}, Value: {item.Value}");
                }
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(sb.ToString());
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine as long as I have granted "List" permission. However by granting "List" permission I noticed that entire Secret list can be accessed. This exposes all other client subscription info which I am not too happy about. I can go and create one Key Vault per each client but that seems to be overkill.

It is possible that I am making a silly mistake and I am not seeing it or it is quite possible that you can't remove "List" permission. Either way I would appreciate if someone with more knowledge can shed light on whether **can I use `AzureServiceTokenProvider` without granting List permission or not?**

**Update: 1**

Found out that there is already issue logged in GitHub for this:
[Handle No List Permission for Secrets](https://github.com/aspnet/MicrosoftConfigurationBuilders/pull/24) and [Azure Key Vault with no List permissions on Secrets fails](https://github.com/aspnet/MicrosoftConfigurationBuilders/issues/21)

**Update: 2**
Based on [Joey's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53882015/1718305) answer this is the final working code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog.Common;
using NLog.Web;

namespace AzureSecretsTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
            try
            {
                InternalLogger.LogFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "logs", "nlog-internals.txt");
                var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
                host.Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
                NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
            }
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) =>
                {
                    //https://anthonychu.ca/post/secrets-aspnet-core-key-vault-msi/
                    //var keyVaultEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEYVAULT_ENDPOINT");
                    //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
                    //{
                    //    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                    //    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                    //    keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(keyVaultEndpoint, "").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    //    //builder.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
                    //}
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

And

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace AzureSecretsTest
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                var keyVaultEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEYVAULT_ENDPOINT");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
                {
                    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                    var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(keyVaultEndpoint, "OneOfTheSecretKey");
                    sb.AppendLine($"Is null or whitespace: {string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(secret.Value)}, Value: '{secret.Value}'");
                }

                //string configValue = configuration["OneOfTheSecretKey"];
                //var children = configuration.GetChildren();

                //sb.AppendLine($"Is null or whitespace: {string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(configValue)}, Value: '{configValue}'");

                //foreach (IConfigurationSection item in children)
                //{
                //    sb.AppendLine($"Key: {item.Key}, Value: {item.Value}");
                //}
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(sb.ToString());
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that using the `AddAzureKeyVault` extension load all your secrets from key vault to make it available in your app. You can either retrieve manually the secret or have a key vault per customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Thomas said, when you use `AddAzureKeyVault` extension to add the `KeyVaultProvider`. At this point, **the middleware has enough information to go and pull all the KeyVault data**. We can immediately start pulling secret values using the Configuration API.

So, if you want to get the specific secret to keep security, you could use the following code.

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

var scret = keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(keyvaultEndpoint, SecretName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```